# Network Load Balancer with the NGINX Ingress Controller on Amazon EKS always returns a 503 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, kubernetes, http-status-code-404

All files referenced are included below. I am trying to create a NGINX proxy to serve my back-end and front-end with the same domain.

Nginx runs successfully, I can tell because I get a 404 error from nginx when I hit the root url given by `kubectl get ingress`.

When I hit the `url/hello` endpoint, however, I get a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` error from Nginx.

Has anyone encountered this error?

Here is the yaml file for my `kubectl create -f` command:

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    # by default the type is elb (classic load balancer).
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
spec:
  # this setting is to make sure the source IP address is preserved.
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    # - name: https
    #   port: 443
    #   targetPort: https

---

kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: go-hello
          servicePort: 8080

---

kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: go-hello
  labels:
    app: go-hello
spec:
  containers:
    - name: go-hello
      image: docker.io/chsclarke11/test-go

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: go-hello-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: go-hello
  ports:
    - port: 8080 # Default port for image
```

here is the Dockerfile for the go-hello app:

```
FROM golang:1.12-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache git

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN go build -o main

# This container exposes port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

# Run the binary program produced by `go install`
CMD ["./main"]
```

Here is the go-hello mock application:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("starting server at http://localhost:8080")
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

Comment: What kind of 404 error? Is it coming from your service or nginx? What URL are you trying?

Comment: @kichik I updated the question to answer. Nginx gives the errors.

Comment: 404 from the root makes sense as you have nothing hosted there. So nginx could literally find nothing to serve. 503 is because it can't reach your server for some reason. Maybe because your service name is `go-hello-service` and not `go-hello`?

Comment: @kichik Thank you!! not sure how i missed that one. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) definition you have specified wrong backend service name: `go-hello` which is not compatible with service name you created for backend - g`o-hello-service`.

Also for the future you can get a  `503`  error from nginx when  `basic-auth`  is enable in the Ingress and the annotation  `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret`  is referencing a non-existing secret.

You can also add the missing secret or removing all  `basic-auth`  annotations from the Ingress can resolve this situation.